# How to CSP restrict to file:/// urls in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, content-security-policy

I have an iframe in a webview which loads a script from the android app's asset using the following :-

```
<script src='file:///android_asset/trusted-iframe-script.js'></script>
```

Now I want to have a content security policy on the iframe such that no other script can be loaded.
For this I added the following to the iframe CSP

```
script-src: 'file:///android_asset/trusted-iframe-script.js';
```

This doesn't work since the file uri is ignored by chrome.

```
The source list for Content Security Policy directive 'script-src' contains an invalid source: 'file:///android_asset/trusted-iframe-script.js'. It will be ignored.
Refused to load the script 'file:///android_asset/trusted-iframe-script.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src file:///android_asset/trusted-iframe-script.js".
```

I read about filesystem uri, but that requires requesting access to the user but I actually only need access to my own assets and not filesystem in general. I also read about blob: urls but that feels akin to inlining the whole script

What is the right way to csp restrict to only file urls ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, this cannot be done for a sandboxed iframe.

Chrome CSP doesn't allow file urls to be whitelisted as a script src. You could use the directive file: (without any url) and that would work if the iframe wasn't sandboxed. But this is a bad idea, since

A. my iframe is sandboxed, and

B. this is an undocumented keyword which may stop working at anytime.

I also tried creating a blob url for the content and instead passing that to the iframe but that too doesn't work unless you set allow-same-origin on the iframe sandbox attribute.

Answer (score 0):

CSP URI's don't have quote marks - so try `script-src: file:///android_asset/trusted-iframe-script.js;`

If that doesn't work most Android browsers now support CSP2, which lets you specify a hash for a supported script.

Answer (score 0):

If the CSP is set on the "page" which contains the iframe you should use
the **​child-src:** directive instead of **script-src:**  ([Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Security/CSP/CSP_policy_directives))

Then, i am not use how to include an assert file and you could try with:

- ​child-src: file:///android_asset/trusted-iframe-script.js

  // i cannot test it
- ​child-src: filesystem:///android_asset/trusted-iframe-script.js

  // [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystem) and check if still requires requesting access to the user
- child-src: https://your.trusted.website.com/trusted-iframe-script.js

  // this should work but it requires to have a trusted server and the app must connect to the web (no obvious condition)